# Fortnite API html

Tags: php, api, server

I want to put my fortnite stats on my website HTML/CSS. I find [this](https://github.com/samhoogantink/Fortnite-API).
But I don't know php very good, so I need your help. Must I delete this: 'your_api_key' and put : your_api_key without the ' ' ?

And lines like this:

```
    $this->auth = new Fortnite_Auth($this);
    $this->challenges = new Fortnite_Challenges($this);
    $this->leaderboard = new Fortnite_Leaderboard($this);
    $this->items = new Fortnite_Items($this);
    $this->news = new Fortnite_News($this);
    $this->patchnotes = new Fortnite_PatchNotes($this);
    $this->pve = new Fortnite_PVE($this);
    $this->status = new Fortnite_Status($this);
    $this->weapons = new Fortnite_Weapons($this);
    $this->user = new Fortnite_User($this)
```

Must I modify something?

(here are some informations:

-user_id: 501b9f2dfda34249a2749467513172bf

-username: NoMaD_DEEPonion

-platform: pc

-windows: season 5

)

For all this code, I used xammp server (I hope it's good)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should always quote `''` your key/strings. So it would look like:

```
$api->setKey('123qwerty456');
$api->user->id('NoMaD_DEEPonion');
```

Please read their [documentation](https://fortniteapi.com/docs/open/1). You're supposed to get an API key from them to get started. And you don't have to edit `Client.php`. You're supposed to include the files instead. Try including `Autoloader.php`, since it requires the necessary files.
XAMPP is alright for development, but not suitable for production/public. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What @sykez wrote.

I personally use https://fortniteapi.com/ to get the data. They also have a sweet POSTMAN page with different requests https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4499368/RWEjoGqD

At last. I am not really sure that this will be a good project to start learning PHP from. I really suggest that you get to understand the basics of PHP first before you jump into API calls, processing arrays and more.